# How to convert a DER file to a PEM file?

Tags: ssl, openssl, pem

I have a public key DER file and i wish to concert it to a PEM file but getting errors and Google isn't helping

Any ideas please?

```
alan@WW031779:/mnt/c/Users/alan/Downloads/RsaCtfTool$ openssl x509 -inform der -in pubkey.der -out certificate.pem
unable to load certificate
140024363618944:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140024363618944:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=X509
alan@WW031779:/mnt/c/Users/alan/Downloads/RsaCtfTool$ openssl x509 -in pubkey.der -inform DER -out private.pem -outform PEM
unable to load certificate
140228465136256:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140228465136256:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=X509
```

Even something simple like

```
openssl x509 -in pubkey.der -out cert.pem
```

Gives me

```
unable to load certificate
139881925907072:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I tried to use pkey as per a suggestion below but get

```
139641461281408:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
139641461281408:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:572:
139641461281408:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
139641461281408:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=RSAPrivateKey
139641461281408:error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:133:
139641461281408:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
139641461281408:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
```

Also rsa

```
alan@WW031779:/mnt/c/Users/alan/Downloads/RsaCtfTool$ openssl rsa -inform der -in pubkey.der -out certificate.pem
unable to load Private Key
140404504073536:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140404504073536:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:572:
140404504073536:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140404504073536:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=RSAPrivateKey
140404504073536:error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:133:
140404504073536:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140404504073536:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
alan@WW031779:/mnt/c/Users/alan/Downloads/RsaCtfTool$ openssl rsa -in pubkey.der -out cert.pem
unable to load Private Key
140227099890304:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
alan@WW031779:/mnt/c/Users/alan/Downloads/RsaCtfTool$ openssl rsa -in pubkey.der -inform DER -out private.pem -outform PEM
unable to load Private Key
140152776102528:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140152776102528:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:572:
140152776102528:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140152776102528:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=RSAPrivateKey
140152776102528:error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:133:
140152776102528:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140152776102528:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
```

Content of my DER file is here https://ghostbin.com/nrsmD and a snippet below

[image]

Comment: `openssl x509` is for X.509 certificates (hence the name). Use `openssl pkey`.

Comment: Have added what I get when I try this @SteffenUllrich - a load more errors

Comment: Looks like you are having an RSA key  - use `openssl rsa` then. Unfortunately there are various kinds how keys can be stored - DER vs. PEM is not the only variation but there are also different ways to have a key in DER etc.

Comment: Afraid not @SteffenUllrich - updated again

Comment: Can you just provide the key so that one can look deeper inside? Note that the screenshot does not help in any way

Comment: What's the best way to do that? I have pasted it here: https://ghostbin.com/nrsmD and also https://file.io/pAimJP0OvoW8

Comment: Note that you give a public key where it clearly expects a private key (see error). You need to use `-pubin` for the public key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239817/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-pee2pee).

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts to convert the DER into PEM the OP provided the DER file in question. Base64 encoded it looks like this:

> BEGINPUBLICKEYMIIB...AwENDPUBLICKEY

The BEGINPUBLICKEY at the beginning and ENDPUBLICKEY look very fishy. Obviously someone took the PEM formatted public key and simply converted it from base64, then claimed that this is DER formatted. Only it is not, since the leading `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and final `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` are not supposed to be included when decoding from base64, only the part between these should be decoded to get to the DER.

After repairing the base64 encoding by removing the wrong BEGINPUBLICKEY and  ENDPUBLICKEY and then properly padding the remaining base64 with `==` decoding successfully lead to a proper DER file.

```
$  openssl base64 -d -in pubkey.b64 -out pubkey.der
```

This then could be transformed to proper PEM

```
$  openssl pkey -pubin -inform der -in pubkey.der -out pubkey.pem
```

Comment: How did you convert the .der-file to this "BEGINPUBLICKEYMIIB...AwENDPUBLICKEY" ?